# Could not connect to SMTP host Permission denied: connect

Tags: java, email, sendgrid

The email is working properly in windows server 2008, but when I changed to windows server 2012, its causing this error.

```
SystemException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.sendgrid.net, port: 25; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

I have googled about this and they told to -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, put this entry in jvm system property and also asked to disabled the antivirus. Both didn't worked. Also I tried contacting the ISP to open the 25 port and now the 25 port is listening. This is my code.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", 25);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    SMTPAuthenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
    mailSession.setDebug(true);
    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    //read the Template and replace values using Velocity Engine
    String text = messageContent;
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    transport.connect();
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
    transport.close();
```

I am using sendgrid, java8, struts 2 and apache tomcat 8.You are my last hope, Please help me with that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your credentials are correct? Can you log them out to verify? Can you try port 587?

Comment: @eddiezane yes, my credentials are correct. I have tried other ports, its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar type of error so i do like this, and now the code is working fine for me Plus i also disable all the antivirus software from my system they generally cause this problem.
Hope it works for you.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  // SMTP Host
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");  // TLS Port 25/587
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  // enable authentication
```